# How to configure docker composer for Laravel/Ngix aplication in EC2

Tags: laravel, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a Laravel application and I'm trying to deploy it to an AWS EC2 instance. What I did was upload the same composer that I use locally for development to the AWS instance and try to make it work. However, it's not working, and I'm a bit lost on whether any configuration is missing. Currently, my docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        container_name: local-nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        restart: always
        networks:
          wp_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.16.200.10
        ports:
            - "80:80" 
        volumes:
            - .:/var/app
            - ./docker/configs/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        links:
            - php
        extra_hosts:
            - "localhost:127.0.0.1"
            - "foo.localhost:127.0.0.1"

    php:
        container_name: local-php
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./docker/configs/php7.4  # Belluno
            #context: ./docker/configs/php7.3 # TG
            #context: ./docker/configs/php5.
            #context: ./docker/configs/php8
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        networks:
          wp_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.16.200.11
        extra_hosts:
            - "database.mysql:172.16.200.12"
            - "localhost:172.16.200.10"
            - "foo.localhost:172.16.200.10"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/app
            - ./docker/configs/php/configs/custom-php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-php.ini
          
    mysql:
        container_name: local-mysql
        restart: always
        platform: linux/x86_64
        image: mysql:5.7
        networks:
          wp_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.16.200.12
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        extra_hosts:
            - "database.mysql:127.0.0.1"
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
            - ./docker/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local
networks:
  wp_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.200.0/24
        gateway: 172.16.200.1
```

And my NGINX configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
    
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name local.lo .local.lo;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error-br.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access-br.log;
        root /var/app/public;
    
        client_max_body_size 32M;
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
    
        location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize=32M \n post_max_size=32M";
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
```

Do I need to change the configuration to make it work? I have little experience creating my own composers and using AWS. I just want to upload this project to the cloud to use in my portfolio.